# Glassfish 4 on Eclipse - times out - java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, timeoutexception

I am having troubles getting a Glassfish server to actually start and stay running on an Eclipse (luna) install.

I have had Glassfish working fine in Netbeans.

I have created the server in Eclipse and I can start it but the progress bar gets to about 69% then stops and eventual give me an error:

> Unable to start server on time.
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

The strange thing is that while I am waiting for the error to come up I can go too localhost:8080 and the server is running and I can go to the admin console as well.

I have increased the timeouts (start was 240sec) as well but the same thing happens.

I have deleted and recreated the server in Eclipse.

I have deleted the cache files from domain1/osgi-cache as advised in other posts

I have setup a second domain (domain2) and tried to connect to that but get the same error.

Any advice would be appreciated.

I am on OSX 10.9.5 as well if that makes a difference.

EDIT - ADDED LOG OUTPUT

```
2015-03-26T17:00:58.880+1000|Info: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)
2015-03-26T17:00:58.883+1000|Info: Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter
2015-03-26T17:00:59.034+1000|Info: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
2015-03-26T17:00:59.145+1000|Info: Authorization Service has successfully initialized.
2015-03-26T17:00:59.200+1000|Info: Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2015-03-26T17:00:59.202+1000|Info: Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.
2015-03-26T17:00:59.209+1000|Info: Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.
2015-03-26T17:00:59.541+1000|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 37ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]
2015-03-26T17:00:59.571+1000|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]
2015-03-26T17:00:59.580+1000|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]
2015-03-26T17:00:59.631+1000|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]
2015-03-26T17:01:01.988+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:02.395+1000|Severe: The SSL certificate has expired: [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=GTE CyberTrust Root 5, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 23741889829347261660812437366387754385443431973861114865490414153884050331745811968523116847625570146592736935209718565296053386842135985534863157983128812774162998053673746470782252407673402238146869994438729551246768368782318393878374421033907597162218758024581735139682087126982809511479059100617027892880227587855877479432885604404402435662802390484099065871430585284534529627347717530352189612077130606642676951640071336717026459037542552927905851171460589361570392199748753414855675665635003335769915908187224347232807336022456537328962095005323382940080676931822787496212635993279098588863972868266229522169377
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Sat Aug 15 00:50:00 AEST 1998,
               To: Thu Aug 15 09:59:00 AEST 2013]
  Issuer: CN=GTE CyberTrust Root 5, OU="GTE CyberTrust Solutions, Inc.", O=GTE Corporation, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    01b6]
Certificate Extensions: 4
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:5
]
[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.32 Criticality=false
CertificatePolicies [
  [CertificatePolicyId: [1.2.840.113763.1.2.1.3]
[]  ]
]
[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
KeyUsage [
  Key_CertSign
  Crl_Sign
]
[4]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 76 0A 49 21 38 4C 9F DE   F8 C4 49 C7 71 71 91 9D  v.I!8L....I.qq..
]
]
]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 41 3A D4 18 5B DA B8 DE   21 1C E1 8E 09 E5 F1 68  A:..[...!......h
0010: 34 FF DE 96 F4 07 F5 A7   3C F3 AC 4A B1 9B FA 92  4.......<..J....
0020: FA 9B ED E6 32 21 AA 4A   76 C5 DC 4F 38 E5 DF D5  ....2!.Jv..O8...
0030: 86 E4 D5 C8 76 7D 98 D7   B1 CD 8F 4D B5 91 23 6C  ....v......M..#l
0040: 8B 8A EB EA 7C EF 14 94   C4 C6 F0 1F 4A 2D 32 71  ............J-2q
0050: 63 2B 63 91 26 02 09 B6   80 1D ED E2 CC B8 7F DB  c+c.&...........
0060: 87 63 C8 E1 D0 6C 26 B1   35 1D 40 66 10 1B CD 95  .c...l&.5.@f....
0070: 54 18 33 61 EC 13 4F DA   13 F7 99 AF 3E D0 CF 8E  T.3a..O.....>...
0080: A6 72 A2 B3 C3 05 9A C9   27 7D 92 CC 7E 52 8D B3  .r......'....R..
0090: AB 70 6D 9E 89 9F 4D EB   1A 75 C2 98 AA D5 02 16  .pm...M..u......
00A0: D7 0C 8A BF 25 E4 EB 2D   BC 98 E9 58 38 19 7C B9  ....%..-...X8...
00B0: 37 FE DB E2 99 08 73 06   C7 97 83 6A 7D 10 01 2F  7.....s....j.../
00C0: 32 B9 17 05 4A 65 E6 2F   CE BE 5E 53 A6 82 E9 9A  2...Je./..^S....
00D0: 53 0A 84 74 2D 83 CA C8   94 16 76 5F 94 61 28 F0  S..t-.....v_.a(.
00E0: 85 A7 39 BB D7 8B D9 A8   B2 13 1D 54 09 34 24 7D  ..9........T.4$.
00F0: 20 81 7D 66 7E A2 90 74   5C 10 C6 BD EC AB 1B C2   ..f...t\.......
]
2015-03-26T17:01:02.434+1000|Info: Java security manager is disabled.
2015-03-26T17:01:02.434+1000|Info: Entering Security Startup Service.
2015-03-26T17:01:02.439+1000|Info: Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.
2015-03-26T17:01:02.471+1000|Info: Security Service(s) started successfully.
2015-03-26T17:01:02.736+1000|Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8080
2015-03-26T17:01:02.745+1000|Info: Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:8181
2015-03-26T17:01:02.748+1000|Info: Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848
2015-03-26T17:01:02.776+1000|Info: Created virtual server server
2015-03-26T17:01:02.778+1000|Info: Created virtual server __asadmin
2015-03-26T17:01:03.303+1000|Info: Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web
2015-03-26T17:01:03.304+1000|Info: Virtual server server loaded default web module 
2015-03-26T17:01:04.044+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.087+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.088+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.089+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.090+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.091+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.093+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.094+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.095+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.096+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.097+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.097+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.098+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.099+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.099+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.100+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.101+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.102+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.102+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.103+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.104+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.104+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.105+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.106+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:04.692+1000|Info: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.0.Final
2015-03-26T17:01:05.036+1000|Info: Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*
2015-03-26T17:01:05.272+1000|Info: Loading application [test_xxxx] at [/test_xxxx]
2015-03-26T17:01:05.275+1000|Info: Loading application test_xxxx done in 6,024 ms
2015-03-26T17:01:05.277+1000|Info: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (13) startup time : Felix (2,715ms), startup services(6,496ms), total(9,211ms)
2015-03-26T17:01:05.364+1000|Info: Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]
2015-03-26T17:01:05.714+1000|Info: JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://xxxxmlerspro2.gateway:8686/jndi/rmi://xxxxmlerspro2.gateway:8686/jmxrmi
2015-03-26T17:01:07.068+1000|Info: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.10.4 2014-08-08 15:09:00...
2015-03-26T17:01:08.059+1000|Info: Listening to REST requests at context: /management/domain.
2015-03-26T17:01:08.195+1000|Info: Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@33cbfa57 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@421a4ee1.
2015-03-26T17:01:08.341+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:08.602+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:08.620+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:08.621+1000|Info: visiting unvisited references
2015-03-26T17:01:09.627+1000|Info: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.7 ( 20140610-1547 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.7@13362) for context ''
2015-03-26T17:01:10.853+1000|Info: Loading application [__admingui] at [/]
2015-03-26T17:01:10.855+1000|Info: Loading application __admingui done in 2,661 ms
```

So it gets to here and I can log into the Glassfish server then it stops with the timeout error after about 4 mins (249secs)

I have just opened and run it in Netbeans and it is fine there.

Comment: Could you provide the full stacktrace for that exception?

Comment: Do you mean the console output for Glassfish?

Comment: Yes it would be part of the console output of glassfish if it had been an exception in glassfish. However I do not see it in the output you posted so the exception is not a problem in glassfish but a problem in eclipse. Does eclipse provide more details on the exception?

Comment: I can't seem to see any other output in Ecplise that could point to the problem?

Comment: It certainly seems to be an Eclipse problem as @Eelke says. Could you try starting GlassFish separately? I would expect Eclipse should be able to detect it as started (though I can't be sure). To do that, go to the glassfish `bin` directory and run `asadmin start-domain domain1` (or whatever your domain name is) and see how Eclipse handles that.

Comment: I can start the server manually through terminal and it functions correctly. But it does not show in Eclipse as running (says 'stopped'). I have tried to 'refresh' the server in Eclipse but it still says that it is stopped. I am not sure if there is a command I can issue from within Eclipse to test? I am trying to migrate a program from Netbeans across to Eclipse. The program is not functioning in Eclipse at present but I don't think it is because of the Glassfish server issue but I would like to know how to get it working in Eclipse like it does in Netbeans??? Thanks for any advice...

Comment: Are you using the glassfish tools for Luna?http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools-luna note that this plugin requires jdk 1.7

Comment: Hi there @Eelke - Yes am using the GF Tools and JDK 1.7. I did try installing Glassfish 3 thinking that the latest version I was using may have been the problem but I still get the same issue. I can start the server OK from within Eclipse (right click then 'start') and it does start OK cause I can go to a browser and navigate to the admin console. But then after a few minutes it just times out with the error as mentioned above - "Unable to start server on time. `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException"` After that the admin console does not work so I assume that the server has been stopped....

Comment: Any other advice cause I am still struggling to get this going. Although the error I get is the same as the other post below (not sure what that was added as an answer?) I don't think it is a bind issue in my case? Anyway it still don't work..... thanks for any advice.

Comment: same problem in ubuntu mate, glassfish 4.1 and eclipse luna

Answer (score 4):

This answer is for other people than the user who post the question.

I had the same problem as you do, But unlike you

> I have deleted and recreated the server in Eclipse.

This has fix it for me. I just remove the server from the eclipse server view. and I create it again. and that's it.

Eclipse Neon, GlassFish 4.1.1, Java EE 7, JDK 8u92, Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

@Lexynux for checking free port in mac osx you can try this command in terminal:

```
sudo netstat -tanp tcp
```

Then in result you can see ports not free.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing debug port to 9009 in eclipse server configuration of glass fish. It is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue as well. It all started with an update of the Glassfish Tools some weeks ago. After that update I was not able to start Glassfish 4.1 via Eclipse. However, I can start it from Netbeans, IntelliJ and from the CLI. Seems to be a bug in the Glassfish Tools Plugin for Eclipse. Many people are facing this issue at the moment! See also [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISHPLUGINS-376).

**To everyone:** Please go to [here](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISHPLUGINS-376) and vote for the issue! This is the only way we can get this fixed!

**I blame Oracle for this disaster!** Someone please take away Java, Glassfish and Netbeans from Oracle!!!! The progress of Glassfish and Netbeans feel to be so dead - bugs are open for months without any reaction! Oracle is throwing all their people onto their "Cloud Strategy".

Well done, Oracle! This is how you make people switch to JBoss/WildFly and some other IDE...

Answer (score 0):

i too faced the same problem. Try to change the network listener port in domain.xml in config folder of the glass fish directory. it may be any ide ,it worked for me .

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOkmuD1QyxQ

Comment: Include the information in your answer. If the video goes away your answer will be much less useful and the information in the video won't be searchable here. Expand on your second sentence and drop the video link.

Answer (score 0):

Increase Perm Size in Glassfish and Eclipse.

In Glassfish:

Open

> glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml

file and find this lines

> `<jvm-options>-XX:MaxPermSize=10000m</jvm-options>`
>
> `<jvm-options>-Xmx10000m</jvm-options>`

and change this 2 values.

In Eclipse:

Open eclipse.ini file in root eclipse folder

> --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
>
> 4g
>
> -Xms4g
>
> -Xmx4g

and change this values.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that GlassFish server didn't boot with the message "Unable to start server on time".

In my case, I was running Jenkins on the same port number (8080).
I was able to boot GlassFish after uninstalling the Jenkins application.

Answer (score 0):

Change the port number , some other server may be using the same port number as grlassfish

Comment: port specification maybe is missing.